How do I rescue a windows 10 system from a failing SSD
Note Before: This is very similar to "Duplicating a system partition from a SSD with bad sectors" however my boot sector is failing and I don't have a valid windows 10 key.
System:
Dell inspiron 1564
256GB SSD
16GB RAM
Originally running windows 7 Home, force updated to windows 10.
Symptoms:
BSOD interval every 5 min's to several hours, does not save a minidump or memory dump. This, along with multiple bad sectors indicated SSD failure. Occasionally defaults to network boot indicating boot sector is corrupting.
Other considerations:
It hosts multiple small websites, email and a game server. The configuration is very complex and so I would rather not re-install over the top. (For all you who are about to give me a verbal bashing for being so insecure, i've been doing this for over 15 years and still have good karma :).
What I have tried:
Bought 2 500GB laptop drives, 7200RPM & 5400RPM
Bought an external HDD sold as a Diskless NAS

Put the SSD in an enclosure and connected it to my PC via USB. Ran backup and restore which failed due to bad sectors.
Used ACMEI backupper to create a backup on the external drive. Replaced the SSD with the new 500GB 7200RPM drive and restored the backup. Files are accessible on the PC, (Yay!) but the drive isn't detected by the laptop as a bootable disc. I think in these new versions of windows the boot sector is on a separate partition? Yes> no??? At some point later today I will put it back in my PC and inspect the partitions to see if both the partitions were copied.

My Ideas:

Set the boot flags manually on the drive. Downside is I have no idea if the boot sector is intact.
Somehow obtain a copy of a windows 10 recovery disc without a valid windows 10 key and run that to see what happens.
Somehow trick the new drive into booting into recovery mode.
Attempt a different imaging method.

Question:
What is the generally accepted method of recovering a force updated windows 10 system, from an SSD with a corrupt boot sector, without having a valid windows 10 license?

If you have a Windows 7 key then you have a valid Windows 10 key since it was already activated on your hardware. You’re spending a lot of time trying to save an installation that isn’t working saving. Just install Windows 10 on a new SSD it will automatically activate. You don’t even have to provide a license when you install Windows 10. You also absolutely do not need a Windows 10 license to download a Windows 10 ISO. Mount the volume in the SSD and get the important configuration file.

Thank you Ramhound for your reply. I did find some useful information in it and if it comes to that I will bite the bullet. If I do take your option it will be relatively easy to restore my files into the new installation however installing the server softwares, supporting softwares, configuring them and setting up the required permissions is extremely complicated for my setup and would take about 2 weeks. This is the part I am trying to avoid. I did attempt to download the windows 10 recovery files but it wanted a valid key, i'll try the windows 7 one.

If it takes 2 weeks to configure. You probably should backup your configuration, it also should not take 2 weeks, to configure a website. You should clone the drive, extract the configuration, and replace the storage device

I do understand what your saying and from where your sitting it probably seems quite simple but from where i'm sitting, along with that there are a website applicationdata users and permissions, FTP and all the admin and folder permissions, hmail server to re-install with it's config and permissions, windows users with their folder permissions etc, the certificates to install into the windows store for the websites and mail server, configuring firewall and ports. This is just all the things I can remember off the top of my head. I wish it were as easy as copy this site and you're done.

Solution-
I created a windows 10 install USB as GPT but the laptop wasn't able to boot it. This alerted me to the laptop being legacy. I then examined the replacement drive and found it was also GPT. Being a second hand drive it had been formatted but the former partitions were intact. This meant that when I restored the backup in AOMEI my MBR backup was restored to a GPT partition.
Fix:

Deleted the partitions
Restored the drive
Put the drive in the laptop and got a windows error about missing hardware
Booted from USB (now MBR) install media and entered command prompt
Ran the following commands;

•Bootrec /fixmbr
•Bootrec /fixboot (this said access denied)
•Bootrec /rebuildbcd
The last one took a while but I got a prompt telling me it had found C:\Windows asking me if I wanted to add it to the boot list and I selected yes.


Make a complete drive image, all partitions.
Install new SSD.
Install Windows 10 from ISO.
Once you have a working Windows 10 PC, restore the valid partitions you want from the image.

